# Why does a button element's height not match that of a sibling input element with same height properties?

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, css

I have the following:

```
<div    style="border:solid 1px gray; height:22px; line-height:22px; display:inline-block;">Div</div>
<input  style="border:solid 1px gray; height:22px; line-height:22px; vertical-align:top;" type="text">
<button style="border:solid 1px gray; height:22px; line-height:22px; vertical-align:top;">Button</button>
```

As you can see in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PwDyk/), Why is the button element 1px shorter than the rest? in Chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has to do with the way the browser implements the box model for those elements.

`div` and `input` both use the `content-box` where-as `button` uses `border-box`

See here for more info: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html

You can add `box-sizing: content-box;`, `-moz-box-sizing: content-box;`, `-ms-box-sizing: content-box;`

to the CSS to force it to use the content-box method of calculating dimensions.

**Edit--More Info**: [Why does Firefox use the IE box model for input elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583882/why-does-firefox-use-the-ie-box-model-for-input-elements)