# button tag vs anchor tag in firefox, problems with text

Tags: css

What is causing this problem shown below with firefox? The first button is a styled anchor tag and the second one is a html5 button tag. In Chrome they both are identical but in firefox you can see the problem with the "LOGIN" text.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="buttonDark">LOGIN<span>›</span></a>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="buttonDark">LOGIN<span>›</span></button>
```

[css is here](http://pastebin.com/QaL8t37U)

The image showing the problem can be found here -->[image](http://img857.imageshack.us/img857/2720/unled3ae.jpg)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381776/why-does-a-button-elements-height-not-match-that-of-a-sibling-input-element-with

Comment: not the same problem.. I already have that code in my css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here for answer: [firefox-problems-with-floated-span-inside-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560141/firefox-problems-with-floated-span-inside-button)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to your code:

```
::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
```

Firefox has button problems galore.  That sometimes fixes them because the 'chrome' Firefox uses is usually defined with some padding and a border, but you can't see either, usually.  This is there so you can have a little dotted border around selected inputs.

Comment: I am already using this. It helps with some other problems but does not help me for my problem.

Comment: Ah, it wasn't in the CSS snippet you gave us.  I'll keep looking.

Could we get the exact webpage?

Comment: sorry its on my local server, but here is the code
html: http://pastebin.com/XDFLfnD
css: http://pastebin.com/m1fp1TEw

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem. Here I have posted the soltuion.

```
    `http://jsfiddle.net/Uysbm/`
```

Comment: Please post the code here. Link only answers are not encouraged on SO because such answers would become of no use when the link becomes inactive.

Answer (score -1):

You are defining the line height. so it will give extra space. you can use this...

```
vertical-align=middle;
```

Comment: Its not by me, but I think you got -1 because "vertical-align=middle;" is a table property.

Comment: I didnt -1ed it but I think it was because of the = sign.. it should have been :.